# Send cookies from nodejs server on ReactJs application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies

How i red [here](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/react-authentication-how-to-store-jwt-in-a-cookie-346519310e81), if i need to send cookie from nodejs to react application both app should be on the same `port`.
 Doing this on the server: `res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true });` 
i can send the cookies on front-end if i have the **same** ports, but here appear the issue if the both apps are on the **same** port, because if i access on front end for example `http://localhost:4001/login` and my server also is on `http://localhost:4001`, i can get the **404** error, because in this way i access the server route `http://localhost:4001/login` not front-end.
 Question: **So How to solve this issue when the routes mess with each other and to be able to send the cookies?**

Answer (score 2):

One of the solutions is to use domains instead of ports.

For this purpose you can launch an edge web server locally (for instance Nginx or Apache) with port forwarding and set mapping from your domain to your localhost.

Also, you can use one of the plenty of services that can expose your local web servers to the Internet. Probably it could be the easiest one for you. Here is the sequence of actions then you can apply to resolve the issue:

**Step 1**

Run frontend and backend apps on two different ports, let's say 4001 for the backend app and 4002 for the frontend app. As a result of the step, you have to be sure that both apps are up and running and accessible via ports.

**Step 2**

Sign up and install https://ngrok.com/ or any other service which can expose your local app to the internet with a domain.
If you will choose ngrok, my suggestion is to write a configuration file and place it in the default location. (default location of config-file depends on your OS - here is the link to the documentation: https://ngrok.com/docs#config-default-location)

Here is the example of a config file:

```
authtoken: // place your ngrok access token here

region: eu

tunnels:
  frontend_app:
    proto: http
    addr: 4002

  backend_app:
    proto: http
    addr: 4001
```

Don't forget to place your authtoken, to get one you have to signup.

For more information about setup ngrok, please check the official documentation: https://ngrok.com/docs#getting-started-expose
https://ngrok.com/docs#tunnel-definitions

As a result after you launch ngrok you have to get the next output in the console:

```
Forwarding                    http://569de0ddbe4c.ngrok.io -> localhost:4002
Forwarding                    https://93b5cdf7c53f.ngrok.io -> localhost:4001
```

And be able to access your local apps via generated external addresses.

**Step3**

The last two things you have to do are:

1. Replace your API endpoint with an external URL (https://93b5cdf7c53f.ngrok.io in my example) in your frontend app.
2. Tweak res.cookie call in the backend app to make possible access cookies from both domains: `res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true , domain: 'ngrok.io' })`

That's it. Now your apps are accessible from the Internet by different third-level domains with shared cookie between them.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I want to ask you if there exist another solution to do this? something shorter, without adding my application on the real server, but something that i can use locally

Comment: You should run your apps on two different ports - it should help. Cookies do not provide isolation by port, so you will be able to access them from your frontend app which will run on different port.

Comment: but according to the docs, cookies are sent from back-end to front-end only if the apps are on the same ports.  But if i run on the same ports i get the issue that i explained above.

Comment: Not sure that is a correct information. Please check the documentation https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265

In the article that you shared above, author suggests to use "proxy" option in CRA - you can learn more about it here in CRA documentation: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/